# How to find $f(x)$ in order to find $f^{(10)}(3)$?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

> (a) Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(x-3)^n}{(2n+1)}$ and its derivative.
>
> (b) Denote by $f(x)$ the function represented by the above power series within its region of convergence. Find $f^{(10)}(3)$, i.e., its 10th derivative at $x = 3$.

I can solve problem (a). However I cannot find f(x). In order to find f(x) how should I do?

Comment: The 10th derivative of your power series centered at 3 is a power series centered at 3! You only need to figure out what the constant term of that series will be.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find $f(x)$. To do part (b), you only need to think about the coefficients of the Taylor series of $f(x)$ at $x=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{\arctan \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}}x^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|\leq 1,x\not =\pm i\!$$
$$x\rightarrow (x-3)$$
$$\frac{\arctan \sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-3}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}}(x-3)^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x-3|\leq 1$$

Comment: All too easy.  +1.

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks so much. But I need to know why my score not increase . Can you help me what I do to repair this

Comment: On my phone, it does indicate an up vote from me.  It's possible someone down voted.

Comment: @Dr.MV No , I collected about 40 but the score not increase

Comment: Have you accrued 200 reputation points for the day (best answer points don't count toward this limit for the day)?

Comment: @Dr.MV Is there a limits of point per day???

Comment: Yes.  200 points is the cap.  But, as mentioned, best vote (15) points do not count toward the 200.  There might be other exceptions, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you so so much.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And if you reached the daily limit, congratulations!  That is a good day.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If we have
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n (x-a)^n,
$$
then the $n$th coefficient $a_n$ is also equal to $\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$.

Comment: You  might want to fix your indices. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks!